# Show that the Quadratic Field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{10})$ does not have the unique factorization property

Tags: number-theory

Directly show that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{10})$ does not have the unique factorization property by considering the factorizations:

$$6 = 2\times 3 = (4 + \sqrt{10})\,(4 - \sqrt{10}).$$

Comment: Do you understand what unique factorization is, or have any idea what the question is asking for? I ask because the fact that you already have two factorizations is pretty important.

Comment: This question already has many answers, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16951/are-mathbb-z-sqrt-17-or-mathbbz-sqrt10-factorial-rings).

Comment: Pretty sure you mean $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]$, not $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{10})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prove that these factorisations do not involve associated elements, i.e. there exists no *unit* $u\in\mathbf Q(\sqrt{10})$ such that $4+\sqrt{10}=2u$ or $3u$, and similarly for $4-\sqrt{10}$.

**Hint**:

Use the norm.